# What is meaning of "fuels" in "fuels practice"?

Tags: meaning

The original text is:

> This online learning platform, which includes an interactive eBook, **fuels** practice so that you truly absorb what you learn and prepare better for tests.

I look meaning of "fuels" at [Merriam Webster Dictionary](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/fuels),  but I don't know which meaning should I choose.

I can understand *"This online learning platform, which includes an interactive eBook"* and *"so that you truly absorb what you learn and prepare better for tests."* And I can also understand "practice", I just can't understand what is meaning of "fuels practice".

At here, what is the part of speech of "fuels"? Noun or verb? And what is meaning of "fuels" at here?

Comment: What didn't you understand about _fuel VERB 2 : SUPPORT, STIMULATE_?

Comment: @MichaelHarvey I'm sorry, English is not my native language. I understand SUPPORT, but I don't know STIMULATE.

Comment: That word is in Cambridge Dictionary too.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Yes. But I couldn't find a suitable meaning.

Comment: **First meaning**: to encourage something to grow, develop, or become active:

Comment: @MichaelHarvey where did you see that "First meaning: to encourage something to grow, develop, or become active:"?

Comment: Cambridge Dictionary.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey if adopt "to encourage something to grow, develop, or become active", it seems that the sentence is not coherent, because It followed by **practice**.

Comment: 'Practice' here is a noun, meaning 'something that is usually or regularly done'. A good teacher encourages practice.

Comment: @Tom  This online learning platform, which includes an interactive eBook, **fuels(= give support to)** practice....

Comment: I think *fuels* is a bad choice of word there, and just *supports* would be better.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Thank you for your explanation of "Practice".

Comment: @Sam Thank you for your explanation, "support practice"  seems that the sentence is not coherent, maybe "do the practice so that you truly absorb what you learn and prepare better for tests." is better to understand.

Comment: @JackO'Flaherty I think use "do the practice so that you truly absorb what you learn and prepare better for tests." is better to understand.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey I think use "do the practice so that you truly absorb what you learn and prepare better for tests." is better to understand.  Because by doing practice(exercises) can help you determine what you have mastered or by doing practice(exercises) can help you determine what you truly absorb.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fuel is a verb in "fuels practice" which means to aid or drive practice.